# Найти стороку регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, grep

Как с помощью регулярного выражения выбрать строки содержащие любой порядок слов?
Например:

Искомая строка "PHP программист"

Будут выбраны строки содержащие оба слова:

- Требуется **PHP** **программист**
- Фирме нужен **программист** со знанием **PHP**

и тд

Comment: А почему не разобрать исходную строку на токены (`"PHP программист"` -> `"PHP"`, `"программист"`) и искать каждый из них в тексте? Так может и побыстрее будет.

Comment: Сейчас у меня ищет grep 'PHP|программист' 'in.txt' > 'out.txt', вот не знаю как сделать чтоб оба проверял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а чем сложнее `grep 'PHP' 'in.txt' | grep 'программист' > 'out.txt'`?

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
grep 'PHP.*?программист|программист.*?PHP' 'test.txt' -E
```

Содержимое `test.txt`:

```
PHP не программист
или нет PHP
программист ли?
тест программист не PHP fail
```

Результат:

```
PHP не программист
тест программист не PHP fail
```

Comment: Вместо `grep -E` можно писать просто `egrep`, просто в вопросе был именно `grep`.